# Device Owner - Get back status bar icons in lock task mode

Tags: android

I have developed device owner application that have some kiosk admin app capabilities.

Among other stuff, I'm using locktask mode in order to disable back button, home button, recent apps button and status bar. And this is all nice.
The problem is that icons (battery, wireless, ....) in status bar are not shown any more, this is not very nice for users .

This apps is intended to be used by company owned industrial devices, and it is very important for those icons to be shown all the time.

Is there any option that I can set in order to get those icons back?

Comment: Do you find an answer or a work around? It seems that this is impossible with task locking.

Comment: any luck with this anyone?

Comment: I'd just implement something in the app to show custom indicators from the android system output

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode?hl=en#customize-ui),

In **Android 9.0 or higher** when lock task mode is enabled, your DPC can enable certain system UI features on the device.

Code below enables the status bar’s system info area that contains indicators such as connectivity, battery, and sound and vibrate options.

```
dpm.setLockTaskFeatures(adminName,
DevicePolicyManager.LOCK_TASK_FEATURE_SYSTEM_INFO |
      DevicePolicyManager.LOCK_TASK_FEATURE_OVERVIEW);
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a workaround for devices using android < 9.0. I am using lock-task mode in android 6.0, and in some cases I need to show the home button to the user.

Comment: yes there is try this:      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                mDevicePolicyManager.setLockTaskFeatures(mAdminComponentName,DevicePolicyManager.LOCK_TASK_FEATURE_HOME | DevicePolicyManager.LOCK_TASK_FEATURE_NOTIFICATIONS | DevicePolicyManager.LOCK_TASK_FEATURE_SYSTEM_INFO | DevicePolicyManager.LOCK_TASK_FEATURE_GLOBAL_ACTIONS);
            }